# Count unique values using a specific date and other criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I want to calculate the unique order number for a specific date given another criterion but couldn't get the right formula.

The spreadsheet is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bqtA10g6Mrk3hDvCuPEFgZz5BUXJN7QQNjMtPtBGMVg/edit#gid=0

You can edit on the formula column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your summary.

E2=

```
  =QUERY({unique(A1:C25)},"Select Col1,Col3, count(Col2) group by Col1,Col3")
```

EDIT:

As per OP's requirements,Adding a Non-intuitive Performance Depreciative Solution:

G2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNT(UNIQUE(IF((E3=$A$1:$A$25)*(F3=C$1:C$25),B$1:B$25))))
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working but it's creating another data. I wanted to dictate the table and create a formula according to the set criteria.

Comment: I've included all your criteria in the formula. It gives only unique order count with names.